# Too many positional arguments for method call with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pylint

I am getting the error `Too many positional arguments for method call` for the line `x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1, SIZE, SIZE, 1)`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

`python3==3.8.3`

`pylint==2.5.3`

`astroid==2.5.3`

`numpy==1.18.5`

Comment: Don't pass too many positional arguments? Look at [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to see what sort of arguments the method is expecting.

Comment: `reshape()` only takes two positional arguments, but you're passing three.  Why are you passing `SIZE` twice?

Comment: You could try to pass a tupple to `reshape` by adding an extra pair of parentheses. `reshape((a, b, c, d))`

Comment: That seemed to have solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ndarray.reshape` method only takes two positional arguments:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape

Comment: Interesting, because the tutorial I was following passed in 4 arguments into the reshape method. Thanks though!

Comment: The `numpy` method allows separate shape values   I use `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` frequently.  Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

With the `numpy` method, any number of positionals are allowed.  It's the function form that requires a tuple.

```
In [20]: np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                           
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [21]: np.reshape(np.arange(24),(2,3,4))                                      
Out[21]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Or something closer to your expression

```
In [25]: np.array(np.ones((3,4),int)).reshape(-1,2,2,1).shape                   
Out[25]: (3, 2, 2, 1)
```

That leaves me wondering about the nature of your `x_train` object. The full error message with traceback might also help.

---

Is this really a Python/numpy error, or a pylint or astroid warning?

Comment: i think it is only a pylint reported error